# Request class injection in repository class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have following repository class

```
    <?php 
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Customer;
use App\Comment;
use App\CustomerCode;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class CustomerRepository {

    use ValidatesRequests;

    public function getAll($search=null,Request $request)
    {
        if($search){
            return Customer::where('name','like',"%$search%")->paginate(5);
        }
        return Customer::paginate(5);
    }
}?>
```

and controller class

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Repositories\CustomerRepository;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerController extends Controller{

    private $customerRepo;

    function __construct(CustomerRepository $customerRepo){
        $this->customerRepo = $customerRepo;
    }

    function index(Request $request){
        return $this->customerRepo->getAll($request->input('search',null));
    }
}
```

this gives me error

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to
>   App\Repositories\CustomerRepository::getAll() must be an instance of
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request, none given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\avmaxapi\app\Http\Controllers\CustomerController.php
>   on line 21

i know i havenot passed 2nd argument but should not it inject automatically

and i donot want to pass request object everytime from controller;

Answer (score 0):

use `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

and not: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;`

at the following:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Customer;
use App\Comment;
use App\CustomerCode;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerRepository {

    use ValidatesRequests;

    public function getAll($search=null,Request $request)
    {
        if($search){
            return Customer::where('name','like',"%$search%")->paginate(5);
        }
        return Customer::paginate(5);
    }
}?>
```

Comment: use global function instead request() and I do not see why u need to use request in that method tho

Comment: but this works via injection in constructor
`class CustomerRepository {

    use ValidatesRequests;
    private $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function getAll($search=null,Request $request)
    {
      if($search){
            return Customer::where('name','like',"%$search%")->paginate(5);
        }
        return Customer::paginate(5);
    }`

Comment: hmm what laravel version are you using ?

Comment: I want to do some query based on token scope and for that i will need request class to access user token

Comment: laravel-----------------------------v5.4

Comment: use request global then request() and remove Request $request since it seems u have messed up smth

Comment: thank you, using global request() method works fine,